# How to use classes to display different screens in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

In my tkinter project I have 2 classes namely `input` and `search` in my code. Both these classes are working well individually and contain a bunch of sub-pages under them through which I'm able to navigate. However I'm not able to switch between the 2 classes. As my project is rather large I have provided my approach as a general code below.

```
InputOrSearch = False


class Input:   # class 1
    [...]

class Search:   # class 2
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen

    def CheckPage(self, page, optmenu=None):
        if page == 1:
            self.Clear()
            self.search_menu()

    def Clear(self):
        for widget in self.screen.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
    [...]


inputscreen = Input(gui)
searchscreen = Search(gui)


def inputorsearch():
    if not InputOrSearch:
        inputscreen.CheckPage(1)
    else:
        searchscreen.CheckPage(1)


while True:
    inputorsearch()

    gui.mainloop()
```

---

This is the approach I have used and although this leads correctly to `Input` it doesn't seem to be working for `Search` for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easest solution is to make each of your classes a subclass of `Frame`. You can then easily switch between them by destroying one and creating an instance of the other, or creating them all at startup and then hiding one and showing the other.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Input(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="I am Input.")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class Search(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="I am Search.")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

def inputorsearch():
    if not InputOrSearch:
        searchscreen.pack_forget()
        inputscreen.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    else:
        inputscreen.pack_forget()
        searchscreen.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


gui = tk.Tk()
inputscreen = Input(gui)
searchscreen = Search(gui)

InputOrSearch = True
inputorsearch()

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: @rish: this _exact_ code isn't working? Or are you saying code that you haven't shown us isn't working? The code you showed us doesn't inherit from `Frame`.

Comment: My code for the classes is working individually, however when I'm trying to implement your suggested code its giving errors.

Comment: Can you update your answer to use ```inputscreen.CheckPage(1)```  and ```searchscreen.CheckPage(1)```  methods. This should be in place of ```.pack```

Comment: @rishi: I don't know what `CheckPage` or `Clear` is supposed to be doing. In general, with my approach  a class should not be putting any widgets in its parent (in your case, `self.screen`) other than itself, nor deleting them from its parent. You shoul dnot be deleting all children of `self.screen` because that would delete both the `Search` and `Input` wigets. `Search` should only have to worry about its children, and `Input` should only have to worry about its children.

Comment: Don't I need a while to be checking for ```InputOrSearch``` continuously?

Comment: @rishi: no, you should not have a while loop in a GUI. That's what `mainloop` is for. You should be switching based on an event, such as clicking a button.

Comment: Thank you for this tip I altered my code a bit to navigate using butttons. I had originally put my ```mainscreen``` inside ```Input```, which I have now brought outside as a function. It's working well now. Although I'm not using the answer you provided, it does seem logical so I will accept it.